# DELETE FROM table WHERE ID='$id' — Variable refuses to stick

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to perform a very simple task here.

I have an `<ol>` that contains 4 rows of data in some handy `<li>`s. I want to add a delete button to remove the row from the table. The script in delete.php appears to have finished, but the row is never removed when I go back and check dashboard.php and PHPMyAdmin for the listing.

Here's the code for the delete button (inside PHP):

```
Print "<form action=delete.php method=POST><input name=".$info['ID']." type=hidden><input type=submit name=submit value=Remove></form>";
```

Moving on to delete.php:

```
<? 
//initilize PHP

if($_POST['submit']) //If submit is hit
{
   //then connect as user
   //change user and password to your mySQL name and password
   mysql_connect("mysql.***.com","***","***") or die(mysql_error()); 

   //select which database you want to edit
   mysql_select_db("shpdb") or die(mysql_error()); 

   //convert all the posts to variables:
   $id = $_POST['ID'];


   $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM savannah WHERE ID='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 

    //confirm
   echo "Patient removed. <a href=dashboard.php>Return to Dashboard</a>"; 
}
?>
```

Database is: shpdb
Table is: savannah

Ideas?

Comment: Can you print i.e. echo "DELETE FROM savannah WHERE ID='$id'"; to see whether  $id really replaced with the value.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Also you must make sure people aren't able to delete arbitrary things by guessing id's. If this is user related data, what stops me from guess id's and removing other peoples information.

Comment: I've written a function I fount on another post... 
    function safe($value){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }

However, encapsulating:
    $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM savannah WHERE ID='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 

with the safe function breaks it... Shall I make another post?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's refusing to stick because you're calling it one thing and getting it with another. Change:

```
"<input name=".$info['ID']." type=hidden>"
```

to

```
"<input name=ID value=".$info['ID']." type=hidden>"
```

because in delete.php you're trying to access it with:

```
$id = $_POST['ID'];
```

You should really quote attribute values as well ie:

```
print <<<END
form action="delete.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="$info[ID]">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove">
</form>
END;
```

or even:

```
?>
form action="delete.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $info['ID'] ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove">
</form>
<?
```

Comment: Thanks cletus. I knew it was simple.

Answer (score 3):

Please, for the love of the web, don't built an SQL query yourself. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 1):

Just another point I'd like to make. I'm 95% sure that you can't give an input a numeric name/id attribute. It has to be like "id_1" not "1".

Also with php you can do arrays.

So you could do this

```
<input name="delete[2]">
```

then in your php

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
  foreach($_POST['delete'] as $key=>$val)
    if($_POST['delete'][$key])  delete from table where id = $val
```